# Prove that $\tan A \tan^2 B \tan C + \tan A \tan B = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given $A + B + C = 180$, prove that

$$\tan \frac{A}{2}\tan^2\frac{B}{2}\tan \frac{C}{2} + \tan\frac{A}{2} \tan\frac{B}{2}= 1$$

I tried
\begin{align}
\tan \frac{A}{2} \tan^2 \frac{B}{2} \tan \frac{C}{2} + \tan \frac{A}{2} \tan \frac{B}{2} &= \tan \frac{A}{2} \tan \frac{C}{2} \ (\tan^2 \frac{B}{2} + 1 ) \\ 
&=\tan \frac{A}{2} \tan \frac{C}{2} \sec^2 \frac{B}{2}
\end{align}

Comment: Could you show us your 'best'? That way we can help you out where you get stuck.

Comment: Please try to write down what you have tried.m:)

Comment: Even the changed problem is wrong. Let $A=B=C=\pi/3$. Then the expression is $\frac{4}{9}$, not $1$.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't hold. Try $A=B=C=\pi/3$.

Comment: The question has been changed. You should now delete this answer (such counterexamples are better suited for comments, because it was likely there was a typo.).

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm new to this site and i can't even make question in html. can you tell me how to delete answers?

Comment: Actually, $A=B=C=\pi/6$ is still a counterexample on the changed question.

Comment: What about $A=B=C=0$ ? ;-)

Comment: @CauchytheDog But then $A+B+C\neq 180^{\circ}$.

Comment: @user236182 BTW, how can I delete my own answer?

Comment: @KayK. It's one of the options written on your answer. There are "share", "cite", "edit", "delete", "flag" in this order, at least on the html version of the site.

Comment: I got this question from my senior in my college, he said that he got this question from a book, so  I don't think it's wrong, even though i can't find out what book it is...

Comment: @StevenKurniawan You can't delete others' answers.

Comment: @StevenKurniawan $A=B=C=60^{\circ}$ gives a counterexample for your question, so the question is wrong. You can check it yourself. If $A=B=C=60^{\circ}$, then the expression is equal to $\frac{4}{9}$, not $1$.

Comment: @user236182 Thanks. Shall I delete it? I see several other comments so not sure if it's okay to delete  now.

Comment: @KayK. Don't delete it because it is still correct, even when the question has been changed.